# Why won't visual studio recognise a typescript type defintion?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have installed Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. 
I have TypeScript set up, working and compiling down to JS.
I have added the EaselJS library, and also a type defintion file for it (called easeljs.d.ts)
I have included the following at the top of my TypeScript file:

```
/// <reference path="easeljs.d.ts" />
```

When I try to type an Easel class type within the TypeScript file it doesn't recognise the type, i.e. if I add 
var circle:Shape;
VS2012 throws the following error in the IDE window -  *the name 'Shape' does not exist in the current scope*

I'm new to TypeScript and may be doing something schoolboy here, but of all the examples I have seen it states this to be the way to include and get type defintions for a 3rd party library.

Any ideas...?

Comment: are you sure that is the correct path to your definition file?

Comment: yes, it's definitely finding that file (if i change the path an error comes up saying the file doesn't exist) i got the file from definitelytyped and it looks legit: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/easeljs/easeljs.d.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it:

I need to reference the class types through the createjs module. 
i.e. 
`var circle:createjs.Shape;` works absolutely fine!